# Loading nextPageToken in UITableViewCell slow and laggy using YouTube api?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, youtube-api

I'm having some issues when lagginess and slowness when loading up the nextPageToken in my UITableViewCell with the youtube api.

When the view loads, the cells are loaded with the default 5 playlists, their thumbnails, and the titles of the playlist like so:

[image]

As the user scrolls down, and more data is fetched via the `nextPageToken`, the cells start to lag.

How can I fix this issue? How can I achieve a smooth loading of the next token like how the YouTube app does?

Here's my code:

```
var playlistItems: [AnyObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    getChannelDetails("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=contentDetails,snippet&channelId=UCJKOvdk-nVzDAFR_9MF64sw&key=\(apiKey)")
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{        
    return playlistItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    // Dequeue the cell to load data
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Playlist", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Reference the video and video title imageview via its tags
    let videoThumbnail = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let playlistTitle = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let playlistVideoCount = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel

    // User scrolled to last element (i.e. 5th video), so load more results
    if (indexPath.row == playlistItems.count - 1)
    {
        print("indexPath.row = \(indexPath.row)")                  

       getChannelDetails("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?pageToken=CAUQAA&part=contentDetails,snippet&channelId=UCJKOvdk-nVzDAFR_9MF64sw&key=\(apiKey)")
    }

    playlistTitle.text = ( (playlistItems[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["title"] as? String

    playlistVideoCount.text = String ( ( ( ( playlistItems[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["contentDetails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["itemCount"]!.integerValue ) ) + " Videos"

    videoThumbnail.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: ( ( ( (playlistItems[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["high"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["url"] as! String )! )! )


    return cell
}

func getChannelDetails(urlString: String)
{   
    let targetURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

    performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in

        if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil
        {
            // Check for valid JSON data by checking for HTTP status code and the error object
            do
            {
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary.
                let resultsDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                // Get the first dictionary item from the returned items (usually there's just one item).
                let items = resultsDict["items"] as AnyObject!

                // Loop through all items and add it to another dictionary
                for (var i = 0; i < self.items!.count; i++)
                {
                    self.playlistItems.append(items[i])
                }

                // Reload the tableview.
                self.videosTableView.reloadData()

                // Hide the progress indicator
                self.progressView.hidden = true
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            print("Error while loading channel details: \(error)")
        }
    })
}

// Make GET Request
func performGetRequest(targetURL: NSURL!, completion: (data: NSData?, HTTPStatusCode: Int, error: NSError?) -> Void)
{
    // Create a NSMutableURLRequest object using the parameter URL object
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: targetURL)

    // Set the GET as the preferred HTTP request method
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    // NSURLSessionConfiguration object
    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    // Pass the object as a parameter to the initialization of the NSURLSession
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    // Instantiate a data task object using the session instance, in which we provide the request as an argument
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            completion(data: data, HTTPStatusCode: (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error: error)
        })
    })

    // Start the fetching process of the data task.
    task.resume()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're performing network requests for data. A delay is expected. Perhaps you just need to load more than 5 at a time? I'd probably shoot for loading 50-100 at once, then another 50-100 when they reach the bottom.

Comment: I requested about 10 this time since the channel doesn't have too many playlists, and it "seems" better, but still not as "snappy" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the implementation details of `performGetRequest` but most likely you are using `NSURLSession` iOS API. [Quite a few places in iOS execute off the main thread](https://youtu.be/oNl7qpUvQ1k?t=3564), ultimately, your performGetRequest is executing off the main thread. If performGetRequest is not executing off the main thread then you have to change that. So you are dealing with multithreading as part of your solution to a snappy U.I.

**UPDATE**

@Dave Batton is correct, you need to load 50-100 records with your initial call to `getChannelDetails` and also make sure that you are displaying a Progress Spinner and not blocking main thread anytime so the U.I. doesn't freeze. You code is not blocking the main thread, please revert my suggested changes:

**Now that I have seen your performGetRequest, change your code back to the way you had it, I left a couple of my comments is all:**

```
func getChannelDetails(urlString: String)
{   
    let targetURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

    //you are leaving the main thread somewhere in performGetRequest
    performGetRequest(targetURL, completion: { (data, HTTPStatusCode, error) -> Void in

         //this closure is called on the main thread sometime later
         //this is the main thread again, because performGetRequest puts your call back function back on the main thread, all this code is fine.
        if HTTPStatusCode == 200 && error == nil
        {
            // Check for valid JSON data by checking for HTTP status code and the error object
            do
            {
                // Convert the JSON data to a dictionary.
                let resultsDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                // Get the first dictionary item from the returned items (usually there's just one item).
                let items = resultsDict["items"] as AnyObject!

                // Loop through all items and add it to another dictionary
                for (var i = 0; i < self.items!.count; i++)
                {
                    self.playlistItems.append(items[i])
                }

                // Reload the tableview.
                self.videosTableView.reloadData()

                // Hide the progress indicator
                self.progressView.hidden = true

            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("HTTP Status Code = \(HTTPStatusCode)")
            print("Error while loading channel details: \(error)")
        }
    })

    //so there is actually a return here back to the line you called      getChannelDetails this happens before the code above in the closure is called.
}
```

Comment: added performGetRequest if it helps..also added in main queue code, but still an "unsnappy UI" :|

Comment: @Pangu I updated my answer, your code is good, you need to load more records and display the appropriate progress spinners in your U.I.

Comment: I've marked yours as the answer, although I'm still disappointed that I notice still some lag even requesting 50 results. I'm wondering how other youtube similar apps like Tubex and TubiMusic obtain such a smooth scroll when pulling data.

Comment: Details of what you mean by lag would be would help give you answers,  other apps use caching techniques server side as well as more complex code in their app, you have to know alot to make awesome apps

Comment: Not sure how I can really describe it, but the scrolling stutters as I scroll up and down. If I scroll fast, there are moments where the scrolling freezes for a second, then continues. In any case, shouldn't I be running the update of the cell UI in cellForRowAtIndexPath in the main thread anyways?

Comment: Can you your project on Github so I can download and look at your code?

Comment: thanks for the help but I actually figured it out. I guess searching within the nested dictionaries within cellForRowAtIndexPath was pretty expensive and caused the lag. I stored it in arrays off site and referenced it using indexPath.row and the scrolling is now smooth like butter :)